# Combinatorics: select permutations if the sum is equal to a given value

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with two columns. The objective is to keep only the combinations of rows, for each "total_sum", where `sum(a) == total_sum`. So we need to generate all the possible combinations using `combn` for example and test them agains total_sum.

I want maximize the number of rows that I keep so when there is more than one solution I want to keep the one with the maximum number of elements.

If two combinations with the same number of elements are possible, then I can keep one or the other.

I actually managed to solve this problem (I think) but my code is really slow. I have to apply this to a large dataset, so there must be a better way to do it.

```
set.seed(42)
dt1 = data.table(a = sample(1:5, 18, replace = TRUE), total_sum = sample(4:8, 3, replace = TRUE))
setkey(dt1, total_sum)
a total_sum
 1: 5         6
 2: 5         6
 3: 5         6
 4: 4         6
 5: 4         6
 6: 1         6
 7: 4         6
 8: 3         6
 9: 5         6
10: 2         6
11: 5         6
12: 5         6
13: 2         8
14: 3         8
15: 4         8
16: 4         8
17: 3         8
18: 1         8
myft <- function(a, total_sum) {
        len = length(a)
        for (i in len:1) {
            valid = match(a, combn(a, i)[, match(TRUE, combn(a, i, sum) == total_sum)], nomatch = FALSE) & TRUE
            if (any(valid)) {
                return (valid)
            }
        }
        return (rep(FALSE, len))
    }
    dt1[, .SD[myft(a, total_sum),], by = .(total_sum)]
   total_sum a
1:         6 1
2:         6 3
3:         6 2
4:         8 2
5:         8 3
6:         8 3
```

Comment: I don't really follow what you're doing.  Maybe if you walk through it step by step as though you were doing it with pencil and paper it would be easier for a fresh set of eyes to rethink it.